# How to disable article checkout in Joomla 1.7?

Tags: joomla, checkout, checkin

How do you disable the checkout functionality. It's pretty useless in my case and the only way to check in is from backend. OpenGlobal didn't work.

Comment: Unfortunately OpenGlobal does not support Joomla 1.7 and I can't find an other module like this one...

Comment: Why would you want to disable checkout? It's there for a reason and if you are saving content properly it should get checked back in automatically. You should never have to use the admin check in if you are saving stuff properly.

Comment: I have some weird people, who don't save or cancel the article editing, so it's left checked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it yourself in the backend: edit the file libraries/joomla/application/component/controllerform.php

remark the following lines the way I did:

```
     // Attempt to check-out the new record for editing and redirect.
/*      if ($checkin && !$model->checkout($recordId)) {
                // Check-out failed, display a notice but allow the user to see the record.
                $this->setError(JText::sprintf('JLIB_APPLICATION_ERROR_CHECKOUT_FAILED', $model->getError()));
                $this->setMessage($this->getError(), 'error');
                $this->setRedirect('index.php?option='.$this->option.'&view='.$this->view_item.$this->getRedirectToItemAppend($recordId, $urlVar));

                return false;
        }
        else {*/
                // Check-out succeeded, push the new record id into the session.
                $this->holdEditId($context, $recordId);
                $app->setUserState($context.'.data', null);
                $this->setRedirect('index.php?option='.$this->option.'&view='.$this->view_item.$this->getRedirectToItemAppend($recordId, $urlVar));

                return true;
//      }
}
```

Comment: Pretty rough, but i guess that'll have to do for now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What about the Autocheckin Plugin for Joomla 2.5? It seems to work for Joomla 3.0 as well. Maybe for 1.7 too.

http://www.joomlaplugin.org/autocheckin-plugin/